# android studio 2.2 not responding when edit build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, centos6.5

I just updated my android studio to 2.2. However the android studio would be not responding for 1 min if I edit build.gradle file, even typing a single space. The other functionalities work well. My operating system is CentOS 6.5. Any helps? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle auto import feature might be cause of problem.
Disable auto import and manually import dependencies.

Comment: My project does not contain dependencies from maven or jcenter. All libraries are inside ./lib folder...

Comment: If you edit `build.gradle` file, android studio gradle plugin automatically re-build everything. So If you add even a simple white space, gradle plugin will try to build your project. @YiChai

Answer (score 0):

It is because Android Studio cannot connect to internet. Setting a proxy fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. If you turn off your network, it will be ok, because Android studio do some network when you edit the `build.gradle` file.

Besides if you have downloaded the `Android Support Repository` and `Google Repository` in the SDK, you Android Studio will work fine.